# What line-polygon clipping algorithm can I use to ensure that the resultant endpoints are always within the polygon?

Tags: floating-point, geometry, numerical-methods, clipping, point-in-polygon

I have a 2D plane, partitioned into n-sided, convex polygons. I'm using [WRF's PNPOLY algorithm](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) for polygon inclusion to ensure that a point belongs inside one and only one polygon.

Is there an algorithm I can use to clip a line segment **PO** to a given polygon in the plane, assuming that `pnpoly(O) == true`, such that **pnpoly(P')** will always be true?

[image: polygon-segment clipping diagram]

My current implementation of clipToPoly does a line-line intersection test with the segment and each edge of the polygon, then uses the intersection point (as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/382431)), but this does not always yield a point that satisfies PNPOLY.

```js
function clipPointToPoly(p, o, poly) {
    var i, j, n = poly.length,
        q, r = {}, s = {}, pq = {},
        rxs, t, u;

    function cross2(v, w) {
        return v.x * w.y - v.y * w.x;
    }

    for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++) {
        q = poly[i];
        s.x = poly[j].x - q.x;
        s.y = poly[j].y - q.y;

        r.x = o.x - p.x;
        r.y = o.y - p.y;

        rxs = cross2(r, s);
        if (rxs !== 0) {
            pq.x = q.x - p.x;
            pq.y = q.y - p.y;

            t = cross2(pq, s) / rxs;
            u = cross2(pq, r) / rxs;
            if (0 < u && u < 1 && 0 < t && t < 1) {
                p.x = p.x + t * r.x;
                p.y = p.y + t * r.y;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Here is my implementation of PNPOLY:

```js
function pnpoly(p, poly) {
    var i, j, e0, e1,
        n = polygon.length,
        inside = false;
    for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++) {
        e0 = poly[i];
        e1 = poly[j];
        if ( ((p0.y > p.y) !== (p1.y > p.y)) &&
             ((p.x < (p1.x - p0.x) * (p.y - p0.y) / (p1.y - p0.y) + p0.x)) ) {
            inside = !inside;
        }
    }
    return inside;
};
```

I don't think I understand enough about the Simulation of Simplicity, or how to deal with PNPOLY's half-open sets when using floating point numbers to handle the edge cases properly.

**For example:**

```
poly: [(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1)]
p: (5,5)
o: (0,0)
p' = (1,1)
```

This fails because (1,1) is not included according to PNPOLY (it's on the open side of the set), but clipToPoly does not take that into account. I suppose I could nudge it by an epsilon if I knew it was on an open end of the set, but I'd prefer a more stable solution.

**Another example:**

```
poly: [-995.9592341908675, -88.48705014724577
       -1040.5031753180106, -176.53192722405026
       -549.9211095905894, -330.8462151682281
       -653.7143990581328, -211.59193148034612]
p: -1032.3773586525654, -208.3586379393678
o: -957.4172402148379, -202.6668958854324
```

In this case, clipToPoly fails because **O** is so close to the edge of the polygon, it doesn't even detect an intersection due to floating point imprecision.

```
t: 1.0000000000000002 u: 0.8306380503739466
```

Is there a way to get clipToPoly's floating point imprecision to match PNPOLY's, so that both are consistent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try exact arithmetics for all calculations: [example](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.exact.html)

Another option (if applicable) - make new polygon ABCDEP', and point will be included always.

Comment: I can't make a new polygon, because that would disrupt the convex tessellation, making the neighboring polygon concave. Regarding exact arithmetics, I don't necessarily need arbitrary precision, I just need my floating point error to be consistent between clipping and polygon inclusion testing.

Comment: @JDS - This question is probably better answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/